# Why Dart can't define an instance property that depends on another instance property

Tags: flutter, dart

[Flutter: The instance member'stars' can't be accessed in an initializer. Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64455240/flutter-the-instance-memberstars-cant-be-accessed-in-an-initializer-error)

I asked the above question and received the following answer as the reason for the error.

> reason : in dart you can't create a class level variable depends with
> another variable

↑ Is there any explanation in the official Dart, Flutter document (or something similar)?

Or is it derived from the Dart constructor mechanism?

If so, I would like to understand how the constructor works, which is the reason for this error.

Is there any relevant part in the official Dart, Flutter documentation, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

It is in fact due to Dart's constructor mechanism, specifically the order of execution during construction, as well as how Dart references instance variables within an object.

From the [Instance Variables](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#instance-variables) section of the [Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour):

> If you initialize an instance variable where it is declared (instead of in a constructor or method), the value is set when the instance is created, which is before the constructor and its initializer list execute.

When you reference an instance variable in a Dart class via `variableName` there is an implied `this` reference to the instantiated object containing the variable. Due to the order of execution of Dart's object construction, `this` cannot reference the object during instance variable declaration because the object has not been created yet. Therefore, `this.variableName` and thus `variableName` (with implied `this`) cannot actually reference the instance variable.

Comment: Please check updated answer for a more complete explanation.